# Какое JRE из трёх выбрать для Rapsbberry Pi | Orange Pi?

Tags: веб-сервер, железо, raspberry-pi, java

Я немного растерялся, что скачивать.
На странице, [на которую попадаешь из гугла](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-arm-downloads-2187472.html), написано: *The JDK for ARM is now offered in the same page as the JDK for other Java SE Platforms.* и через 20 секунд переадресацию [сюда](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), и сам [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html), где нет ничего по арму, а отдельно ссылка [JRE для ARM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/index.html), которую нужно успеть нажать. В итоге имеем целый список из шести вариантов:

1. Linux ARM 32 Hard Float ABI (JDK)
2. Linux ARM 64 Hard Float ABI (JDK)
3. ARMv5/ARMv6/ARMv7 Linux - SoftFP ABI, Little Endian 2
4. ARM v6/v7 Linux - VFP, HardFP ABI, Little Endian
5. x86 Linux Small Footprint - Headless
6. to create customized JREs using the [JRECreate tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/jrecreate.htm#JEMAG270)

Теперь список вариантов Raspberry и прочих фруктов:

1. Rasp Pi 1. Broadcom BCM2835 0.7GHz ARM11.
2. Rasp Pi 2. Broadcom BCM2836 0.9GHz Quad-Core ARMv7l Cortex-A7.
3. Rasp Pi 3. Broadcom BCM2387 1.2GHz Quad-Core ARMv8 Cortex-A53 64bit
4. Orange Pi 1. Allwinner H3 Quad-core 1.0GHz Quad-Core ARMv7 Cortex-A7.
5. Orange Pi 2. Allwinner H5 Quad-core ?GHz Quad-Core ARMv8 Cortex-A53 64bit.

И заодно спрошу - какой лучше выбрать для мини-сервера для Jira, Redmine + web-сайта? На процессоре ARMv8 или ARMv7?

Comment: для Jira никакой RPi не выглядит подходящим. Она с легкостью съедает 1GB хипа.

Comment: см. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15354/does-atlassian-jira-run-well-on-the-raspberry-pi

Comment: Есть ещё Orange Pi 2E и другие с 2ГБ оперативки и частотой 1,6 и есть даже c 8 ядрами. Вопрос не в этом, а в сопоставлении процессора и версии JRE. А ведь там ещё помимо этого и опции есть client, minimal, server. Я просто как пример сказал.